# Split stock quote to tokens in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to read a text file of stock quotes and do some processing with each stock data (i.e. a line in the file).

The stock data looks like this :

```
[class,'STOCK'],[symbol,'AAII'],[open,2.60],[high,2.70],[low,2.53],[close,2.60],[volume,458500],[date,'21-Dec-04'],[openClosePDiff,0.0],[highLowPDiff,0.067],[closeEqualsLow,'false'],[closeEqualsHigh,'false']
```

How do I split the line into tokens where each token is what is enclosed in the square braces, .i.e. for the above line, the tokens should be `"class, 'STOCK'"` , `"symbol, 'AAII'"` etc.

Comment: The output is a list of strings ?

Comment: @Ofiris Yes, the output is a list of tokens, where each token is a string

Comment: @Dhara I tried some regex that I got from SO, for example `print (re.findall('\[[^\]]*\]|\"[^\"]*\"|\S+',str))` . But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

str="[class,'STOCK'],[symbol,'AAII'],[open,2.60],[high,2.70],[low,2.53],[close,2.60],[volume,458500],[date,'21-Dec-04'],[openClosePDiff,0.0],[highLowPDiff,0.067],[closeEqualsLow,'false'],[closeEqualsHigh,'false']"
str = re.sub('^\[','',str)
str = re.sub('\]$','',str)
array = str.split("],[")
for line in array:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

`print(re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", inputline))`

Or perhaps without regex:

`print(inputline[1:-1].split("],["))`

Comment: The non-regex solution you gave was my first thought too.  It's not very robust, but if the data is consistent enough, it'll work to read it in to help rewrite it in a saner format..

Answer (score 1):

Start with:

```
re.findall("[^,]+,[^,]+", a)
```

This would give you a list of:

`[class,'STOCK']`, `[symbol,'AAII']` and such, then you could cut the brackets.

If you want a functional one liner, use:

`map(lambda x: x[1:-1], re.findall("[^,]+,[^,]+", a))`

The first part splits every second `,`, the map (for each item in the list, use the `lambda` function..) cuts the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s = "[class,'STOCK'],[symbol,'AAII'],[open,2.60],[high,2.70],[low,2.53],[close,2.60],[volume,458500],[date,'21-Dec-04'],[openClosePDiff,0.0],[highLowPDiff,0.067],[closeEqualsLow,'false'],[closeEqualsHigh,'false']"

m = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9']+)", s)
d= { x[0]:x[1] for x in m }

print d
```

you can run the snippet here : `http://liveworkspace.org/code/EZGav$35`